# Prometheus returns error context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring

I deployed Prometheus [with an Helm chart from Rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/monitoring-alerting). Targets such as Alertmanager, Prometheus, Grafana, Node-exporter, Kubelet etc. are configured automatically. The endpoint from alertmanager refers to the IP address of the specific pod for example. I also configured multiple targets successfully like Jira and Confluence.

Since the service [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) is running in the namespace `kube-system`, it's also configured automatically. But only this service is getting the error `Context deadline exceeded`.

I checked in a random pod if those metrics are accessible by running the command `curl -s http://<IP-ADDRESS-POD>:7979/metrics`. Also did this with the service ip address (`kubectl get service external-dns` and `curl-s http://<IP-ADDRESS-SVC>:7979/metrics`).
Both of these curl commands returned the metrics within a second. So increasing the scrape timeout won't help.

But when I `exec` in the Prometheus container and use the `promtool debug metrics` command it shows the same behaviour like in my browser. The external-dns returns a timeout with both of the IP addresses and if I try this with another target it just returns the metrics.

I also don't think it's a SSL issue, because I already injected the correct CA bundle for the targets Jira and Confluence.

So anybody an idea? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit the NetworkPolicy in the `kube-system` namespace. The containers from the `cattle-monitoring-system` namespace are now allowed to access the containers from the `kube-system` namespace. [You can upload your NetworkPolicies here](https://editor.cilium.io) and it visualizes which resources has access or not. The NetworkPolicy looks like this now:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-network-policy
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: cattle-monitoring-system
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```